# CMFCButton not doing crossfade state animation when the mouse is over the button

Tags: button, mfc, visual-studio-2017

I have reviewed a few articles about using [CMFCButton](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/cpp/mfc/reference/cmfcbutton-class) but I still have a question.

My button has a image on the left and a caption on the right. There is nothing fancy, except I am using **WindowsBlinds 10** on my computer (I have deactivated it and the issue remains).

With regular buttons they highlight when the mouse is over them. But this is not so with the `CMFCButton`. The best I came up with is to set the style to **SemiFlat**.

Mouse **not** over control:

[image: Mouse not over control]

Mouse **over** control:

[image: Mouse over control]

If I set the style to **Style 3D** then you see no change at all whether the mouse is over the button or not.

Why is the `CMFCButton` not following the rules? Is there a setting? I don't want to use owner drawn.

Comment: On my system (Win 10, VS 2015) the `CMFCButton` has the normal mouse-over behaviour, just like a regular button. I can later check this with VS 2017 too. Besides, you can have an icon even on a regular `CButton`, you just have to assign the icon in code via `CButton::SetIcon()`.

Comment: @zett42 In my case I am loading a PNG 32 transparent resource and passing the `HBITMAP` handle. I am not sure if that can be done with the regular `CButton`. I await your feedback for **VS2017**.

Comment: Works with VS2017 too. Though I noticed that `CMFCButton` doesn't show the state animation (crossfade), another argument for using `CButton` instead. As for using a transparent bitmap, there is `CButton::SetBitmap()`.

Comment: @zett42 Yes it is the cross fade I mean. But can the normal button be bitmap and caption?

Comment: Sure! Just don't set neither `BS_ICON` nor `BS_BITMAP` styles. This information is missing from the MFC documentation but it can be found for the [`BM_SETIMAGE` message](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb761822(v=vs.85).aspx) which MFC sends internally.

Comment: I have it working. Please see my updated question. If you want to provide an answer about using `CButton` I will accept it. Thank you.

Comment: _Yes it is the cross fade I mean_ - you should update your question then. You can also answer your own question, I don't care about the rep. points.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the comments provided I have changed to a `CButton` as that renders as I need out-of-the-box!

[image: Updated Dialog]